# Microsoft Excel - Dynamically filter contents from one sheet to another and update as new content is entered

Tags: microsoft-excel

I've created an advanced filter to copy the filtered contents of one sheet to another sheet.  But when new data is entered into the first sheet, the content in the second sheet is not updated unless I redo the advanced filter manually every time.

Is there anyway to do this dynamically so the content in sheet two always reflects the content in sheet one?

Comment: Have you looked into pivot table/reports?

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

This can be accomplished with an **Event** macro.  The macro would monitor changes in the first worksheet and automatically update the second worksheet if the first worksheet changes.

The macro details would depend on the structure of both worksheets.